# How to create CellTable based on the response from the server

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.2-celltable, celltable, gwt-celltable

1. I want to create a CellTable. But Columns of the celltable should be based on the response from the server. I'm getting the server response as List.

   ```
   No of Columns = Size of the list.
   ```
2. CellTable column header should be the value from the server.
   For ex. Server response: `List<Contacts> contacts`

   Header should be `contacts.getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by the following code.

```
          for (Contacts contact : contacts) {
               final String city = contact.getCity();
               final TextColumn<String> addressColumn = new TextColumn<String>() {

                @Override
                public String getValue(Contacts object) {
                    return city;
                }
            };

            cellTable.addColumn(addressColumn, contact.getAddress());
            }
```

Regards,
Gnik

Answer (score 0):

Use `CellList` with an [AsyncDataProvider](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html):

```
//Create a cellList
@UiField
CellList<Contact> cellList;

//Creating dataProvider and completion of the cellList
@UiFactory
CellList<Contact> makeCellList() {
private AsyncDataProvider<Contact> provider = new AsyncDataProvider<Contact>() {
    @Override
    public void onRangeChanged(final HasData<Contact> display) {
        rpcService.getContact(new AsyncCallback<List<Contact>>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(List<Contact> result) {   
                   display.setRowData(0, result); 
               }
               @Override
               public void onFailure(Exception ex) {
                    //TODO
               }
        });
    }
};

//Adding the cellList to the provider in a constructor
provider.addDataDisplay(cellList);
```

Here's full [example](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/javadoc/com/google/gwt/examples/view/AsyncDataProviderExample.java?r=8944) and [docs](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#data-provider).

Comment: Thanks Andrey. But I must use CellTable not CellList. CellTable is our client's requirement.

Comment: Anyway use the `AsyncDataProvider`. Here's applicable [example](http://www.mytechtip.com/2010/11/gwt-celltable-example-using_8168.html).